# Properties of dictionary order topology

Tags: general-topology

Properties  of dictionary order topology

Choose the correct option

[image]

My attempt :  According to Munkres  the order topology  on $\mathbb{R} \times  \mathbb{R}$ has  as basis the collection of all open interval  of the forms ( $a\times b$ ,$ c \times d$) for  $a < c$ and for  $a =c$ and $b <d$

so  according to the definition  option c) will be the correct answer

Is its true ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base for the topology is all sets of the form $[0\times 0, a \times b)$ and $(a \times b, 1\times 1]$ and all open intervals of the form $(a \times b, c \times d)$ where both endpoints lie in the square. (we have to treat the minimum and maximum of the set a bit differently).

I think (C) is indeed the correct option.

Comment: one  more  confused @henno sir     here  question asking  closure of S  i mean  $ \bar S $?   Is   $S=  \bar S$?  im  little bits  confused

Comment: @jasmine I agree with your choice of c for the closure of $S$. What more do you want to know?

Comment: i mean $(a,b) $    that is  the closure of $(a,b) =[a,b]  $   so  why we not used $[a,b]$?

Comment: @jasmine because not every neighbourhood of $(a,0)$ intersects $S$.

Comment: What about $(a,1)$ and $(b,0)\ $?

Comment: In order to check whether $(a,1)$ is a limit point of $S$ or not we need only to check whether or not the following neighbourhood of $(a,1)$ intersects $S$ namely, $$((a,q), (r,s))$$ where $0 \leq q \lt 1, a \lt r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq s \leq 1.$ By density property of $\mathbb R,$ the above neighbourhood contains points of the form $\left (x, \frac {3} {4} \right ).$ Take any $a \lt x \lt \text {min} \{r,b\}.$ Similarly, one can show that $(b,0)$ is also a limit point of $S.$